# SQL: Insert multiple sets of values in one statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Is it possible to insert multiple sets of values to a SQLite table in one statement?

I was trying:

`INSERT INTO the_table VALUES (1,2,'hi'),(2,0,'foo');`

with the different ()s representing different insert sets, but I get an error.

Comment: Posting the error message will give you better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are there only three columns in your table?  If not, you could try defining the column names you are setting like so:

```
INSERT INTO the_table 
       (column1  ,column2  ,column3) 
VALUES (1        ,2        ,'hi'   )
      ,(2        ,0        ,'foo'  )
```

This convention was introduced in SQL Server 2008 known as the [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx). See MSDN's [INSERT page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for a look at the overall syntax. Also, the `INSERT` statement can be easily formatted for better readability.

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, could you at least comment as to why this is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
INSERT INTO the_table 
SELECT 1,2,'hi'
UNION
SELECT 2,0,'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was found that syntax in MSDN but after trying I can't do that too, than I note that in the bottom of the page was written that there is an error in the page :) where is link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx see the bottom **How to insert multiple rows**